# PHP not responding to exec

Tags: php, exec, wget

```
exec('wget  --progress=bar  http://technabob.com/blog/wp-
content/uploads/2011/04/light_up_pi_symbol_1.jpg');

echo "1";

output   1
```

ie the download is not working.I m sure that the command is correct. I believe it has something to do with my Apache.Any help will be appreciated.
The image is not getting downloaded.

I was wrong about Apache . I think it is about `wget` because I can run other commands on my server using

```
$output = `ls -al`;
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was that I didnot specify the download location so it was saved at some random location. But still the command was working right.
The correct method could be 
$command="wget --output-document=/var/2 --progress=bar  http:/"."/technabob.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/light_up_pi_symbol_1.jpg";

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Apache. Also, read the documentation for `exec()`. Most likely you'll see that that function call *replaces* the current process with the one specified in the argument, meaning that the rest of your code won't get run.

UPDATE

Perhaps the PATH is incorrect? Try using the full path to the wget command instead. Also, the current working directory will be used as the download destination for your command and the process may not have permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: So according to you download shld take palce and echo "1" should not

Comment: Excuse me, I've just looked up the PHP function and I'm wrong. It doesn't replace the current process (unlike in every other programming language). See `man 3 exec` for what that usually means. Go figure.

Comment: I have checked permission of a number of folders including /usr/bin. Could you pinpoint a few ones?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure .. you need to understand that your scripts run as a certain user. In general you can use /tmp for downloads but really you'd be better off using a network connection directly rather than forking a separate process (wget). I assume PHP can do this.